Can I set VS Code to use tabs for indentation and spaces for leading alignment?
Is there a way to get VS Code to use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment)?  As an example:
function foo(){
\t--array.map(a => a[0])
\t--     .filter(a => a);
}

In this case, \t-- indicates a tab, and spaces indicate spaces.  As is, my spaces get converted to tabs all the time and it's very frustrating.

That's not gonna be easy for VSCode either, in terms of how it will be able to tell that the line .filter(a => a) should be aligned and not intended. For a human it's easy to tell, but for a machine not very.

@Cristik It really shouldn't be that hard - just treat spaces immediately following tabs as "not whitespace".  I don't expect it to automatically align my code, just to respect the alignment that I've put in.

At the time of this writing, no. It's been raised as a feature request before:

Spaces for alignment should be respected when "Editor: Insert Spaces" is disabled #134618 (actually I don't know this issue ticket is closed. but it's on the backlog)
Alignment is incorrectly replaced by tabs
#184700 (didn't receive enough community support in time to get added to the backlog)

I don't understand why #134618 is closed. I've pinged a maintainer to ask why.
